# NodeJs Async / Await / Promisse

Tags: javascript, node.js, async

estou com uma dúvida, preciso fazer com que o código abaixo, aguarde o .map ser executado, sendo que a função parseCategory() faz uma chamada à uma API para obter os artigos. Acontece que a saída do console "final..." é executada antes do término do .map.

Alguém tem uma dica sobre qual seria a melhor prática?

```js
async function parseCategories () {
  var categories = ["business", "entertainment", "health", "sports", "technology"];
  var articles = [];
  await categories.map(category => {
    parseCategory(category).then(result => {
      articles.push(result);
      console.log(category);
    }).catch(error => {
      logger.fail(error);
    });
  });
  await console.log("final...");
}
```

Comment: um possivel solução seria usar promise, e promise.all para executar as promises em paralelo mas mostrar o valor ordenado

Answer (score 0):

Conforme comentando, o promisse.all seria uma alternativa para você resolver este problema. O seu código ficaria da seguinte forma:

```js
async function parseCategories () {
  var categories = ["business", "entertainment", "health", "sports", "technology"];
  var articles = [];
  await Promise.all(categories.map(category => {
 try {
  result = await parseCategory(category);
  articles.push(result);
 }  catch(error){
  logger.fail(error);
 }
  }));
  await console.log("final...");
}
```

Aqui tem uma outra forma de resolver este problema:

https://flaviocopes.com/javascript-async-await-array-map/

Comment: Olá Bins, obrigado pela resposta, o problema que continua é que preciso aguardar o retorno do método parseCategory() que executa uma chamada à API... para depois dar um push em articles e depois finalizar...

Answer (score 0):

Simulei aqui o retorno da sua função, e consegui retorna ordenado dessa maneira, utilizando promise.all

```
async function parseCategories () {
  var categories = ["business", "entertainment", "health", "sports", "technology"];
  var articles = [];

  var result = await categories.map(category => {
            parseCategory(category).then(result => {
              articles.push(result);
              console.log(category);
            }).catch(error => {
              logger.fail(error);
            });
          });


  var con = await console.log("final...");

  Promise.all([result,con])

}
```

Comment: Olá Luan, obrigado pela resposta, o problema que continua é que preciso aguardar o retorno do método parseCategory() que executa uma chamada à API... para depois dar um push em articles e depois finalizar...

Comment: e como está seu parseCategory? ta como async? não entendi o problema, em teoria deveria executar o parseCategory primeiro para depois executar o .then